# What it is going to be evaluated in a boolean expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean-expression

assuming that I have the following variables

```
bool b;
int i;
T* ptr;
```

when I put `b`, `i` or `ptr`, or whatever other variables I have, in a boolean expression like

```
var1 && var2
```

What is going to be evaluated to solve this expression ? The C++11 standard says something about what is the part from `var1` and `var2` that contributes to determine the boolean result ? There are implicit casting ?

It's not clear to me what the standard says about this.

---

EDIT

I'm interested in how a generic `T` type is converted into a `bool` and how a boolean expression is solved according to the standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§5.14/1

> The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to type `bool` (Clause 4)... Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

§4/2

> [*Note:* expressions with a given type will be implicitly converted to other types in several contexts:
>
> — When used as operands of operators. The operator’s requirements for its operands dictate the destination type (Clause 5).
>
> ...

This is about as clear as the standard gets. First `var1` will be implicitly converted to `bool`, and then, if it is `true`, `var2` will be implicitly converted to `bool`.

**Edit:** I'll quote also §4.12/1

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

**Edit 2:** For some arbitrary type `T`, see §4/3,

> ... Certain language constructs require that an expression be
>   converted to a Boolean value. An expression `e` appearing in such a context is said to be *contextually
>   converted to `bool`* and is well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable `t` (8.5).

For the meaning of this initialization, see §8.5/16

> — Otherwise, if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, conversion functions are considered.
>   The applicable conversion functions are enumerated (13.3.1.5), and the best one is chosen through
>   overload resolution (13.3). The user-defined conversion so selected is called to convert the initializer
>   expression into the object being initialized. If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the
>   initialization is ill-formed.

There is even more detail in §13.3.1.5 and §13.3, but you will be reading all night and then some. But the bottom line is that if `T` is a class type, then there has to be a conversion function. The best practice would be to define `explicit operator bool` for the class. However you could also do something like `operator void*`, which is what `std::ios` and its derived classes define, because `void*` can then be converted to `bool` in a standard conversion sequence. (This should be regarded as a deprecated idiom in C++11.)

Comment: none of your quoting dont say "how", my point is exactly "how", what is supposed to happen and how this is being evaluated.

Comment: Well, your question didn't use the word "how" at all. It's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: @user2485710 it depends on the type and whether it defines any custom conversion functions. For numeric and pointer types, non-zero/non-null are true while zero/null are false.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan what "custom conversion functions" are ? there is a table for reference ?

Comment: @user2485710 I added another paragraph to my answer.

Comment: @user2485710 defining something like "operator bool() const { return ... ;}" in your class would be an example of such a function.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you're asking about. A variable is true in C and C++ if it is non-zero. The && operator only evaluates the right operand if the left operand is true. The truth value of an instance of a class T doesn't exist unless there is a conversion function. This is all in the standard.

Comment: the last part of your answer is about `short circuit evaluation` and that's not my point. According to the first part of your answer I should assume that the `lvalue` alone contributes to the expression ?

Comment: I don't know *what* your point is, and I said so. There are no l-values in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Well I've already told you how a variable is converted to a Boolean, and I've answered the only question I can see about how Boolean expressions are solved. What's your question now?

Comment: it looks like you are referring to primitive types like `int` or `bool`, your question doesn't really address how a language like `C++11` addresses the generic case, for example for an instance of a custom defined type `T`, like a new class, what is "non-zero" ?

Comment: @user2485710 For user defined types, you need conversion operators. Either to `bool`, or to something that can be implicitly converted to `bool` (i.e. any other user defined type.) But you messed up your question by putting only primitive types in the example (`T*` is a pointer, regardless of the type of `T`.)

Comment: The truth value of an instance of a class T doesn't exist unless there is a conversion function, as @MichaelAaronSafyan has already told you. Your question remains unclear and it also seems to keep changing. Please make a proper effort to ask a proper question.

Comment: @juanchopanza this thing is way too simple to be true. There must be a giant pitfall somewhere. I just have to write an operator for my `class` that returns `bool` ?

Comment: @EJP I'm trying to clear the air, sorry for the mess, but that's the clearest thing that I can write at this point, Your initial answer seems to be a solution by the way ...

Comment: @user2485710 or some other built-in type, unless the operator is marked `explicit`. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/78IOl2).

Comment: What @juanchopanza and Michael Aaron Safyan have both told you is exactly the case, and what Brian Bi said too. I don't know why you find it's 'too simple', pitfall-ridden, etc. It isn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza well, I see, but it's basically the other way around, at that point we are back to the "non zero thing".

Comment: @EJP I guess that I have trust issues with the language

Comment: @user2485710 The other way around to *what*?? Perhaps you should ask a real question.

Comment: Nobody can help you with your 'trust issues'. We can only tell you how the language works. I don't know what you mean by 'the other way around'. What you've posted here exhibits a severe terminology misuse problem, for a start, and that may be causing all sorts of other comprehension difficulties.

Comment: @juanchopanza I couldn't agree more. I'm downvoting this question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think that your example is valid, as I said, it's like a workaround, for example if I make that operator `explicit` it doesn't even compile. You example relies on the fact that you are returning something that is non-zero and there is an implicit cast involved. http://pastebin.com/wM7LKZyV

Comment: and apparently this operators or "custom conversion functions" are following some kind of overloading rules.

Comment: @user2485710 It is not a work-around. It is how you get instances of user defined types to be useful in boolean expressions.

Comment: @user2485710 Please stop this. You don't seem to be a competent judge of what is valid. In fact you're just exhibiting blind phobias here. It's of no interest or value. If you have a proper question, which you evidently don't, please post it.

Comment: it's not a phobias, the example is supposed to work and it doesn't when restricting the rules of the game, also considering that example, this is 100% equivalent as far as the boolean expression is concerned `'x' || false`, that's why I said that is something that goes back to the non-zero concept, but doesn't really explain anything about how expression are evaluated, plus I don't get the overload thing, is `operator bool() const` the one with the highest precedence ?

Comment: At last a real question. Sort of. Highest precedence compared to what? It is obviously higher than && and ||, otherwise it wouldn't *work.*

Comment: @EJP well I would like to see the criteria for the precedence, at this point that's the main focus and the only thing left to solve to understand this "custom conversion functions".

Comment: @juanchopanza plus, I have another doubt about this, on some `C` code, there is the usual `!!var` trick being used, this trick gets a `bool` out of a number, it's `false` when the number is `0`, it's true otherwise, according to what your post says, this trick is useless and it's just a waste of computation. The thing is this trick is used is some good code like the linux kernel, which isn't a really bad project at all.

Comment: @user2485710 Well, that's a different language. There are many C hacks that are just not necessary in C++. This one might stem from the fact that C didn't have a boolean type until C99. I guess the linux kernel needs to be backwards compatible or it is too risky to change critical code that works well.

Comment: @user2485710 What do you mean by 'criteria for the precedence'? You've already been told that it must be higher than the logical operators, with a proof. In fact you've already had half the C++ standard quoted at you by Brian Bi, specifically §4/3, and you've already ticked that answer as correct. What's the problem now?